# How can you recommend videos based only on completion rates and upvotes?

Tags: correlation, recommender-system

I'm working on a recommendation system where the only available data are video completion rates and up-votes (no ratings or down-votes). Most of the users have not voted on anything.

What would be a good approach to recommending videos based on this limited information? Could I do something similar for "related videos"?

I was thinking about counting videos-completed as an implicit "like", then up-votes counting as a higher score, then performing a Pearson correlation. Would that make sense? I really appreciate any input. Thank you!

Comment: If the number of users are small you can have a vector for each user, each element of the vector would be completion rates and up-votes for each user. Then you can use k nearest neighbors to find the most similar user and recommend videos based on that. You can start getting create ways to rank the videos from the info form the neighbors.

Comment: @JosephSantarcangelo thanks for the tip! When you say "each element of the vector would be completion rates and up-votes for each user" - do you mean every user has a single vector where each element represents a score for the video? The score being some composite of completion rate and up-vote?  Or were you implying that each user should have a vector for each video?

Comment: each 1)every user has a single vector, 2) each element represents a score for the video 3) k nearest neighbors 4) then the score is a some composite of completion rate and up-votes 5) this video may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uxXPzm-7FY